# Twig compare two values in different arrays

Tags: symfony, twig

First of all I'm learning Twig. 
I was wondering if it is possible wit Twig to compare two different values from different arrays/lists?!

I have two list of items I call them like so:

```
{% if page.cart %}
{% for product in page.cart.products %}
  {{ product.id }}
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

And:

```
{% if products %}
{% for product in products %}
  {{ product.id }}
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

I want to compare both `product.id`'s so I can create a new statement. Is there any way to compare both values? The idea is to check if an id is present in `page.cart.products` and if so then do something.

I want to create a new statement to display some info. Something like so:

```
{% if page.cart %}
{% for product in page.cart.products %}
  {% set cartId %}{{ product.id }}{% endset %}
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}

{% if products %}
{% for product in products %}
  {% set listId %}{{ product.id }}{% endset %}
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}

{% if cartId == listId %}
.... do this ....
{% endif %}
```

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: It's impossible to do it that way with two differents loops if you are looking for one single ID.

Comment: Why not compare it controller and return the result? it's more efficient than return 2 variables then compared in view just for showing one result.

Comment: @ColourDalnet: Ok but could you give an example then? I really don't know where to start since I'm pretty new to Twig

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can loop over one array and check if the `id` is present in the second one. If it's there, you can do something.

```
{# In case you want to store them, you can do so in an array #}
{% set repeatedIds = [] %}
{% for productCart in page.cart.products if page.cart %}
    {% for product in products if products %}
        {% if productCart.id == product.id %}
            <p>This id -> {{ product.id }} is already in page.cart.products</p>
            {% set repeatedIds = repeatedIds|merge([product.id]) %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
{{ dump(repeatedIds) }}
```

It's a very basic search algorithm and the cost is quadratic. Obviously, there are more efficient ways to look for an element in an array (though more complicated to implement).

If the amount of products you have to deal with is not very big, you could use this solution. However, if you have, let's say, more than one hundred products in each array (or you feel that the algorithm is slowing down your loading time), you could do this process in the controller using more sophisticated methods and PHP and just pass the result to the template.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This not exactly what I'm looking for but it gave me some good insights for looping over arrays.